# WSO2 Identity Server Dashboard Issue : SSL peer failed hostname validation for name: <IP> (/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag#27)

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

WSO2 IS (5.7) is running in an ec2 instance. MgtHostName and HostName are updated in repository/conf/carbon.xml with the ip of the instance. Carbon console can be accessed without any issue, but when trying to load the dashboard (https://x.x.x.x:9443/dashboard) below error is given. Any guidance on this would be really helpful.

> HTTP Status 500 - org.mozilla.javascript.JavaScriptException:
>   JavaException: org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException:
>   SSL peer failed hostname validation for name:{x.x.x.x}
>   (/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag#76)

And in the server logs,

> [2019-10-14 20:48:58,125] ERROR {JAGGERY.acs:jag} - 
>   org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped
>   org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: SSL peer failed
>   hostname validation for name: {x.x.x.x}
>   (/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag#27)    at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1754)
>     at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148)  at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
>     at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
>     at
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.c0._c_call_1(/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag:27)
>     at
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.c0.call(/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag)
>     at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
>     at
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.c0._c_callWSReturnXML_3(/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag:67)
>     at
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.c0.call(/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag)
>     at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
>     at
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.c0._c_callWSReturnJSON_4(/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag:82)
>     at
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.c0.call(/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag)
>     at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
>     at
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.login_logout.c1._c_login_1(/dashboard/controllers/login-logout/SAML2SSOAuthenticationClient.jag:18)
>     at
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.login_logout.c1.call(/dashboard/controllers/login-logout/SAML2SSOAuthenticationClient.jag)
>     at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
>     at
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.c6._c_script_0(/dashboard//acs.jag:67)
>     at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.c6.call(/dashboard//acs.jag)   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)

Comment: I think the hostname validation is blocked in loadbalancer, here you can see an similar problem https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/2763

Comment: @mleaf
Actually I haven't used lb here. Directly calling the ip:port of the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve this by importing pk12 file of the selfsigned cert to wso2carbon.jks and adding internal ip mapping in the ec2 instance. More details can be found in [this blog](https://medium.com/@igunawardana/how-to-change-hostname-in-wso2-is-with-self-signed-certificate-ea547605e015).